# how to loop all submenu items in a menu strip level

Tags: c#, database, loops, menustrip

I've been trying for weeks on how to loop all the items in my `SubMenu` on the `MenuStrip`. My problem is if I add a new `SubMenu` is I have to input a code to loop it again to control my items. Basically I am looping my `SubMenu` just to control my items. What I want is to loop all items in the `MenuStrip` level not on submenu level

here is my hierarchy. 
[image]

here is my code

```
public void startUpRoleControl()
    {
        loadRoleControl();
        disableAllToolStripItems();

        bool varmasterDropItem = false;
        bool varservicesDropItem = false;
        bool varreportsDropItem = false;
        bool varmaintenanceDropItem = false;
        bool varuseroptionsDropItem = false;

        if (dtDBRoleControl.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            foreach(DataRow drmaster in dtDBRoleControl.Rows)
            {
                foreach (ToolStripItem masterDropItem in masterToolStripMenuItem.DropDownItems) // use to disable sub items of mastermenu
                {
                    if (masterDropItem.Tag != null)
                    {
                        if (masterDropItem.Tag.ToString() == drmaster["rprevformname"].ToString() && Convert.ToInt32(drmaster["rprevview"]) == 1)
                        {
                            masterDropItem.Visible = true;
                            varmasterDropItem = true;
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            foreach (DataRow drservices in dtDBRoleControl.Rows)
            {
                foreach (ToolStripItem servicesDropItem in servicesToolStripMenuItem.DropDownItems) // use to disable sub items of mastermenu
                {
                    if (servicesDropItem.Tag != null)
                    {
                        if (servicesDropItem.Tag.ToString() == drservices["rprevformname"].ToString() && Convert.ToInt32(drservices["rprevview"]) == 1)
                        {
                            servicesDropItem.Visible = true;
                            varservicesDropItem = true;
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            foreach (DataRow drreports in dtDBRoleControl.Rows)
            {
                foreach (ToolStripItem reportsDropItem in reportsToolStripMenuItem.DropDownItems) // use to disable sub items of mastermenu
                {
                    if (reportsDropItem.Tag != null)
                    {
                        if (reportsDropItem.Tag.ToString() == drreports["rprevformname"].ToString() && Convert.ToInt32(drreports["rprevview"]) == 1)
                        {
                            reportsDropItem.Visible = true;
                            varreportsDropItem=true;
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            foreach (DataRow druseroptions in dtDBRoleControl.Rows)
            {
                foreach (ToolStripItem useroptionsDropItem in reportsToolStripMenuItem.DropDownItems) // use to disable sub items of mastermenu
                {
                    if (useroptionsDropItem.Tag != null)
                    {
                        if (useroptionsDropItem.Tag.ToString() == druseroptions["rprevformname"].ToString() && Convert.ToInt32(druseroptions["rprevview"]) == 1)
                        {
                            useroptionsDropItem.Visible = true;
                            varuseroptionsDropItem = true;
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            foreach (DataRow drmaintenance in dtDBRoleControl.Rows)
            {
                foreach (ToolStripItem maintenanceDropItem in maintenanceToolStripMenuItem.DropDownItems) // use to disable sub items of mastermenu
                {
                    if (maintenanceDropItem.Tag != null)
                    {
                        if (maintenanceDropItem.Tag.ToString() == drmaintenance["rprevformname"].ToString() && Convert.ToInt32(drmaintenance["rprevview"]) == 1)
                        {
                            maintenanceDropItem.Visible = true;
                            varmaintenanceDropItem = true;
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }



            if (varmasterDropItem == true) // shows master item if there is a item in master that are visible
            {
                masterToolStripMenuItem.Visible = true;
            }
            if (varservicesDropItem == true)// shows services item if there is a item in services that are visible
            {
               servicesToolStripMenuItem.Visible = true;
            }
            if (varreportsDropItem == true)// shows services item if there is a item in services that are visible
            {
                reportsToolStripMenuItem.Visible = true;
            }
            if (varmaintenanceDropItem == true)// shows services item if there is a item in services that are visible
            {
                maintenanceToolStripMenuItem.Visible = true;
            }
            if (varuseroptionsDropItem == true)// shows services item if there is a item in services that are visible
            {
                userOptionsToolStripMenuItem.Visible = true;
            }

        }
```

as you can see the more submenu I have the more code I have to control. Is there any other way to loop all the items in main menu. I am using a database to control the visibility of the all the menu items. is there a way to that using a minimal loop statement and not loop per submenu

Comment: Could I suggest, it would be great if you can provide us the overview of your menu items. I mean just a hierarchy of your menu items will be good.

Comment: my heirarchy is menustrip -> submenu -> menuitem

Comment: main menu -> master -> employee master. is there an another way to automatically detect all the items in my main menu strip?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, So here is what I could try based on your image/example
(This loops through all your menu and submenu items and then set's its Visibility -- Tested in Visual Studio 2010):

```
public void startUpRoleControl()
{
    loadRoleControl();
    disableAllToolStripItems();

    if (dtDBRoleControl.Rows.Count > 0)
    {               
        for (int i = 0; i < menuStrip1.Items.Count; i++ ) //menuStrip1 is the main menu strip which holds the menu items.
        {
            foreach(DataRow drmaster in dtDBRoleControl.Rows)
            {
                ProcessDropDown(menuStrip1.Items[i], drmaster["rprevformname"].ToString(), Convert.ToInt32(drmaster["rprevview"]) );
            }
        }
    }
}

private void ProcessDropDown(ToolStripItem item, string rprevformname, int rprevview)
{
    ToolStripMenuItem menuItem = (ToolStripMenuItem)item; //Type casting from ToolStripItem to ToolStripMenuItem
    if (!menuItem.HasDropDownItems)
        return;
    else
    {
        foreach (ToolStripMenuItem val in menuItem.DropDownItems)
        {
            if (val.HasDropDownItems)
                ProcessDropDown(val, rprevformname, rprevview);
            if (val.Tag != null && val.Tag.ToString() == rprevformname, && rprevview == 1)
            {
                val.Visible = false;
                menuItem.Visible = false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Considering the above, I suggest that you are doing too much overhead with deciding the menu items visibility on a value

**Update**:

Just to ensure the error of type casting wont occur, you can check whether the item is convertible, as:

```
    private void ProcessDropDown(ToolStripItem item)
    {
        ToolStripMenuItem menuItem = item as ToolStripMenuItem; //Type casting from ToolStripItem to ToolStripMenuItem
        if (menuItem == null) 
            return;

        if (!menuItem.HasDropDownItems)
            return;
        else
        {
            foreach (var val in menuItem.DropDownItems)
            {
                ToolStripMenuItem menuTool = val as ToolStripMenuItem;

                if (menuTool == null) 
                    continue;

                if (menuTool.HasDropDownItems)
                    ProcessDropDown(menuTool);
                if (menuTool.Tag != null && menuTool.Tag.ToString() == "nagaraj")
                {
                    menuTool.Text = false;
                    menuItem.Visible = false;
                }
           }
        }
    }
```

Comment: this might work. Ill try to play with your suggestion. I'm just curious, is there no function or built in function of c# to return all the "menuitems" in a "menustrip" regardless of the hierarchy?

Comment: As much as I can tell, about what I know, you can only get `submenuitems` by `DropDownItems` and in case for entire menu set repeat the same in a `MenuStrip`, that also has to be a loop. Since .Net provides the enumerator for the dropdowns, they might expect us to fetch it :)

Comment: is there a code to loop that can let you use array style for the mainmenu or toplevel. sample like this mainmenu[2]->submenu[3]->item.

Comment: I am guessing you mean: `menuStrip1.Items[i]` which I have in a loop. So the main menu strip is looped and accessed to get its menu items. But `menuStrip1.Items[i]` gives `ToolStripItem` which is a base class in hierarchy of `ToolStripMenuItem`. (that's why the conversion). Then the `ToolStripMenuItem` objects have `DropDownItems`. Hence it helps us to loop like `menuStrip1.Items[i]->DropDownItems[i]->item` (Hypothetically)

Comment: thats what I'm missing. the typecasting of toolstripitem to toolstripmenuitem. Ill fondle with your code a bit ^_^

Comment: @Mandz So what was the result? :)

Comment: sorry I've been busy for the past 2 days until now with other issues. I'll leave the comment and pick answer after I implement it in my project.

Comment: hello sir after a week of technical work. I'm back in the project. @LearningNeverStops there is a little problem with the code your post. the thing is how can detect if the ToolStripMenuItem is a toolstripseparator. Error occur when type casting toolstripseparator type to ToolStripMenuItem.

Comment: @Mandz Could you try with the typecasting successful by using `as` and checking for `null` ? Just verify, if not, I will execute the code and check later :)

Comment: here is the error. Additional information: Unable to cast object of type 'System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripSeparator' to type 'System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripMenuItem'. the error is highlighting the foreach (ToolStripMenuItem val in menuItem.DropDownItems). I think the menuItem.DropDownItems cannot be typecasted when the value is toolstripseparator. I'll try to reconstruct the code to fix the error.

Comment: I tried your code but still the same error. The thing is the the separator is detected inside the foreach statement not on the upper part of the code and by the way // if (!menuItem) // is not working or has highlighted as a redline

Comment: Give me sometime I will execute and check :)

Comment: @Mandz There you go, that would solve your problem :) Updated the section at the last inside for loop.

Comment: I also think that your code will work. Ill try it out today. I need to fondle a bit to implement my database with it

Comment: Your suggestion in update is working. thx. I just need to recode to add the database section

Answer (score 0):

No one can give you an exact answer. However, here is the lead for you to play with Linq.

```
public class AccessRight
    {

        public string FormName { get; set; }
        public int CanView { get; set; }
    }

    public void ApplySecurity() 
    {
        // --- 
        if (dtDBRoleControl.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            // first loop through your database rows. 
            // create a small POCO to perform actions.
            List<AccessRight> accessRights = new List<AccessRight>();
            foreach(var drmaster in dtDBRoleControl.Rows){
                var access = new AccessRight() { FormName = drmaster["rprevformname"].ToString(), CanView = Convert.ToInt32(drmaster["rprevview"]) };
                accessRights.Add(access);
            }

            // close your database here...




            // now for each menu call a method as given below

            PerformActionOnMenu(masterToolStripMenuItem, accessRights);
            PerformActionOnMenu(servicesToolStripMenuItem, accessRights);
            PerformActionOnMenu(reportsToolStripMenuItem, accessRights);
            PerformActionOnMenu(maintenanceToolStripMenuItem, accessRights);


        }
    }

    private void PerformActionOnMenu(ToolStripMenuItem menuItem , List<AccessRight> accessRights)
    {
        var result = from item in menuItem.DropDownItems
                         where item.Tag != null && item.Tag.ToString()
                         join x in accessRights on x.FormName.Equals( item.Tag) 
                         select new { DropDownItem = item, Access = x};

            if ( result != null && result.Count() > 0 ) 
            {   
                menuItem.Visible = true;        
                foreach(var r in results ){
                     r.DropDownItem.Visible = true;
                }
            }
    }
```

Comment: what is linq? sorry if i ask a stupid question. I just migrated from vb6 so that is the first time had heard about linq. ^_^

Comment: umm try reading form here http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/101-LINQ-Samples-3fb9811b It is a way to run query against IEnumerable objects.

Answer (score 0):

Change strip to whatever you called your MenuStrip control.

```
private void startLoop()
{
    for(int a = 0; a< strip.Items.Count;a++)
        recursiveLoop(strip.Items[a]);
}

private void recursiveLoop(ToolStripMenuItem item)
{
    //DO YOUR LOGIC HERE
    item.Visible = true;
    //
    for(int a = 0; a< item.Items.Count;a++)
        recusiveLoop(item.Items[a]);
}
```

Didnt test it but it should work like this. You might need to check for types if you use seperators since i dont remember if they are a seperate control as ToolStripMenuItem. Just change the recursiveLoop argument to Control and check in inside typeof(item) and compare it to everything you use and do stuff acording to what it is and your other parameters